# Trying to get correct/exact string from json

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I am trying to get string from JSON, that i should use later. The problem is that my code (depending which file i use) doesn't give me my string with special characters. Strange thing is that one file does everything right, while other is not, even through they contain exactly the same PHP code.

This is that i get from the first one:
    `[title] => 1611 PlikiÅ¡kiaiâ€“Kriukai`  (Incorrect)

And from another:
    `[title] => 1611 Plikiškiai–Kriukai`  (Correct one)

Here is some code:

```
function get_info($id) {                
    $json = file_get_contents('http://restrictions.eismoinfo.lt/');
    $array = json_decode($json, true);

    //get object/element with such id, so then it would be possible take needed parts/values
    $result_array = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($id == $value['_id']){
            $result_array = $value;
        }
    }

    //Street name
    $title = $result_array['location']['street'];
    echo $title;
}

get_info($id); //$id is some string like 143crt9tDgh5
```

1st file is located in folder "test", while 2nd in "project".

Any ideas why is that happening?

Comment: I see this url throwing error 500

Comment: make array like this` $result_array[] = $value;`

Comment: In this case it will return error. I need only 1 value, id's are unique.

Comment: Make sure your .php files are in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you vitalikaz